# Copy rows and change corresponding values

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have 4 tables
[image: Tables with Relations]

Tables are used to store product attributes and its values in different languages

I'm trying to copy attribute (copy in same table to new row and increment/change some values).
First 3 tables connected with **pk_i_id** and it's easy to copy and increment values.

When copying rows in **oc_t_attribute_value_locale** table, I can't change **fk_i_attribute_value_id** column values to corresponding new values as in **oc_t_attribute_value** table

Here is my query code

```
/* Copy attribute with id 35 in -- oc_t_attribute --  table */
SET @refid := 35;
INSERT INTO oc_t_attribute (`s_identifier`, `b_enabled`, `b_required`, `b_search`, `b_hook`, `b_values_all`, `s_category_id`, `i_order`, `s_type`, `s_search_type`, `b_search_range`, `b_check_single`, `s_search_engine`, `s_search_values_all`, `s_icon`, `fk_i_linked_to_attr_id`, `s_restrict_type`)
SELECT s_identifier, b_enabled, b_required, b_search, b_hook, b_values_all, s_category_id, i_order, s_type, s_search_type, b_search_range, b_check_single, s_search_engine, s_search_values_all, s_icon, fk_i_linked_to_attr_id, s_restrict_type
FROM oc_t_attribute
WHERE pk_i_id = @refid;

SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID(); /*  @last_id_in_table1 = 68  */

/* Copy attribute data for id 35 in -- oc_t_attribute_locale -- table */
INSERT INTO oc_t_attribute_locale (`fk_i_attribute_id`, `fk_c_locale_code`, `s_name`)
SELECT @last_id_in_table1, fk_c_locale_code, s_name
FROM oc_t_attribute_locale
WHERE fk_i_attribute_id = @refid;

/* Copy attribute data for id 35 in -- oc_t_attribute_value -- table */
INSERT INTO oc_t_attribute_value (`fk_i_attribute_id`, `fk_i_parent_id`, `s_image`, `i_order`) 
SELECT @last_id_in_table1, fk_i_parent_id, s_image, i_order
FROM oc_t_attribute_value where fk_i_attribute_id = @refid;


/* Copy attribute data for id 35 in -- oc_t_attribute_value_locale -- table */
INSERT INTO oc_t_attribute_value_locale (fk_i_attribute_value_id, fk_c_locale_code, s_name)
  SELECT fk_i_attribute_value_id, fk_c_locale_code, s_name
   FROM oc_t_attribute_value_locale vl
   WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL
      FROM oc_t_attribute_value v
      WHERE v.pk_i_id = vl.fk_i_attribute_value_id
        AND v.fk_i_attribute_id = @refid
   )
```

[image: Results After Copy operation]